# navigating the IOS sources

Tags: open-source, codenameone

I'm having trouble navigating the IOS VM sources - strictly for reading not,
not compiling.  For example where would I find the IOS implementation of Class.forName(String).   I find it should be called forNameImpl which I can't find anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The specific code is under the `BytecodeTranslator` since its part of the VM. You can find that function [here](https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/vm/ByteCodeTranslator/src/nativeMethods.m#L717-L731).

A lot of low level system calls are in that source file.